# Capsule Network reconstruction layer

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I am experimenting the capsule network, using the architecture provided here:
[Capsule Network in Mathematica Deep Neural Network Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/CapsNet-Trained-on-MNIST-Data)
While I can figure out what the network do following the capsule paper from Hiton et al. 2017; I am really confused about the reconstructing part, especially the **pick** module:
[image: Capsule Network Architecture]
I can extract this part out. But I am wondering how this is illustrated in the paper, and what each operation is for.
Thanks for the attention.

Comment: The construction notebook `NetModel["CapsNet Trained on MNIST Data", "ConstructionNotebook"]` has lots of information. It looks like the Pick layer is specially built with more low-level functionality than the rest of the network.

Comment: The functions in use in that custom `Pick` layer are described in the [MXNet NDArray API Documentation.](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/ndarray/ndarray.html) I haven't read the paper but it seems like the functionality of the layer should be relatively clear after reading the documentation for ['broadcast_axis'](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/ndarray/ndarray.html?highlight=broad#mxnet.ndarray.broadcast_axis) and ['pick'](https://mxnet.incubator.apache.org/api/python/ndarray/ndarray.html?highlight=pick#mxnet.ndarray.pick).

Comment: Can you add a link to the paper on Arxiv or similar to your question?